# Exposed tire wire- safe to drive home?

Tags: tires, safety

I need to drive 20 miles on the highway home, is this tire safe to to do that or is the wire a serious concern? I've driven 10 miles on it so far. [image: Tire]

Comment: Mine is worse been driving on it for a week now at speeds of 65 cause of procrastinaters in my household won't take it to the shop to make it a priority.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me preface this by you do any of this **at your own (and passenger's if any) risk**. That said, you *should* be able to drive this the extra 20 miles to get it home. I would drive slowly (back roads, 35mph maximum) if possible. The idea with that is to keep heat in the tire down to a minimum. Also, if it does blow out, you should be able to keep the car under control while you pull it over to the side. I have seen tires in worse shape make it further, but no two tires are the same.

There are two things to think about with your tire here. First, what caused the tire to wear unevenly. Secondly, instead of going home, you should think about taking it to a tire shop to get it replaced. When you get it home as it is, what are you going to have to do then? Take it to a shop to get the tire replaced, but you'll have a bunch more miles on it.

Comment: Thanks, I'm just going to drive it to a tire shop. Just wanted to make sure it wasn't seconds from completely dieing and I didn't know.

Comment: Looks like it might be a good time for an alignment, too.

Comment: @Ellesedil ... exactly why I suggested looking into the *why* this was happening. Sucks to put a brand new tire on there only to have it torn to shreds in a couple thousand miles. I do believe the picture was taken at an angle, though. Makes it look like the tire is leaning quite a bit.

Comment: @Paulster2, I don't think so: look at the wear patterns: the inner edge is worn flat.  The middle and outer grooves are nearly untouched.  I think you could hide a pencil in there, much less pass the penny test.

Comment: @TheoretiCAL, also, if you have wire cutters, you may want to trim the longer wires before driving.  They can tear the heck out of your wheel well...

Comment: @BobCross ... I didn't say it *wasn't* leaning, just that the picture is taken at an angle which makes the lean look far greater than it actually is. The tire itself is just plumb worn out. Hardly any tread left at all across the entire width.